# How to get item in RecyclerView when select this item in Spinner in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-spinner

How to link Spinner items with RecyclerView sections? I have added Spinner in actionBar and fill it with some items like (first, third...) and when choose item like (third) how to get third section in RecyclerView to come to top screen? also when scroll in RecyclerView sections how to change in Spinner depend on RecyclerView sections?
And where do that in Activity or RecyclerView Adapter?

In RecyclerView Adapter:

```
class ParentAdapter(private val list: List<Parent>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<ParentAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {

    inner class MyViewHolder(val viewDataBinding: RecyclerViewParentBinding) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(viewDataBinding.root) {

    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ParentAdapter.MyViewHolder {
        val binding =
            RecyclerViewParentBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
        return MyViewHolder(binding)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ParentAdapter.MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.viewDataBinding.section.text = list[position].section
        }
    }
```

In Activity:

```
val mainBinding = binding.mainRecycler
        mainBinding.apply {
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@MainActivity)
            adapter = ParentAdapter(list)
        }

spinner.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
            override fun onItemSelected(
                parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {
                // ???
            }

            override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I can only say it this way: separation of concerns.

```
Repository -> Produces List

Activity <-> ViewModel <-> Repository <- List
\
 -> Receives List -> Populates Spinner
 -> Receives List -> Populates Recycler View

Spinner -> Selects Item
        -> Activity -> Informs ViewModel Item N has been selected

ViewModel -> Receives selection, transforms data that RecyclerView will use.
          -> Emits selection back to activity

Activity -> Receives new State from VM, updates RecyclerView with data.

RecyclerView -> Via its adapter, re-binds and/or performs the operations it needs to reflect the new state.
```

Separate your problem into small responsibilities.

Comment: Thank you, but I can't understand explaining without examples, how to do this and what can I put in code?